# Complex analysis (triangle inequality)

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to prove: $$|z|\leq|Re(z)|+|Im(z)|$$

Work done so far: 
I know how to prove the triangle inequality for two vectors but I am not sure how to show it holds for two components of a single vector. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider the vectors $(x,y)$, $(x,0)$ and $(0,y)$.

Comment: @RobertZ You are right, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $|z| = \sqrt{|Re(z)|^2+|Im(z)|^2}$, and the inequality follows immediately after squaring both sides.

Comment: Thank you so much, sometimes a hint is all one needs!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use $z=\text{Re }z+i\,\text{Im }z$ and the conventional triangle inequality:
$$|z|\le|\text{Re }z|+|i\,\text{Im }z|=|\text{Re }z|+|\text{Im }z|.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer!